# Symfony/Twig: How to get error Message from hidden fields

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have defined 3 hidden fields in my formtype:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'hidden', array(

            ))
            ->add('number', 'hidden', array(

            ))
            ->add('token', 'hidden', array(

            ))
        ;
    }
```

When I send my form, I get a notValid Error from my Controller, thats totally correct. But when I want to get the errors in my twig-template, no errors were set.

```
{{ dump(myForm.card.type.vars.errors|length) }} //<--- IS ALWAYS 0
```

But when I change the formtype fields to `"text"` instead of `"hidden"` I get the correct length of 3.

Is it different to get the erros for hidden-fields?

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!

Comment: If this to troubleshoot, you can use the Web Debug Toolbar to view all the form request and validation.

Comment: `{% if not myForm.vars.valid %} error {% endif %}` should do the trick

Comment: The problem is, I have other text fields where I check exactly for an error

Comment: I can confirm that behaviour of forms in Symfony and Twig. Rendering specific field errors in Twig using the `{{ form_errors(form.myField) }}` helper seems to work only for non-hidden fields. Those error messages for hidden fields can only be rendered with `{{ form_errors(form) }}`. Disabling `error_bubbling` for the hidden field as suggested by Vidy Videni in the first answer works like a charm to make `{{ form_errors(form.myHiddenField) }}` possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also meet this problem today, my solution is :

Set error_bubbling as `false`

```
$form->add('shippingAddress', 'hidden', [
    'label' => 'acme.form.checkout.addressing.shipping_address',
    'data' => $addressId,
    'error_bubbling'=>false
]);
```

Display the error using this way

```
{{ form_label(form.shippingAddress) }}
{{ form_errors(form.shippingAddress) }}
{{ form_widget(form.shippingAddress) }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Searched too long for that solution. Setting `error_bubbling` to `FALSE` was absolutely what I needed to do. (Working with Symfony 2.8, by the way.)